# How I add substring in here ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

ok, I want to add substring for my view,

this for my code

```
@Html.ValueFor(x => x.rol_tb_form1.pengusul.Substring(5,5))
```

and this for my error

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
>       current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
>       about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used 
>       only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or 
>       single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

can someone fix my code??

Comment: why not @Model.rol_tb_form1.pengusul.Substring(5,5)

Comment: You can't use `Substring` in helper's lambda expression. If you don't have any `DisplayFormat` for the property, then you could try the above comment

Answer (score 0):

more ways to do that example,

```
@{ string _substring = Model.rol_tb_form1 == null ? string.Empty : Model.rol_tb_form1.pengusul.Substring(5, 5); }
```

and you can call it in your view just like this

```
@_substring
```

make sure this data (rol_tb_form1) not null,

jadi dliat dulu itu ada isinya apa ngga, kalo ada baru di panggil di view, biar gak error

kasih point yah mas kwkwkw

dengan catatan, itu Model.rol_tb_form1 itu emg ada foreignkey di model classnya yak, kalo ngga ada katakan lah string biasa, yahh tinggal

```
@Model.YourField.Substring(5,5)
```

no need use html helper, sorry for bad english hahahaha